# Styling applied to the wrong place

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, menu, stylesheet

Please help, I am trying to simply add a border at the last element of my sub menu and text indent for the sub-menu elements, but for some reason it just applies everything on the top of the page, please take a look at the image below, it applies the changes on the top of the page for some reason and not on the elements it self!

for Live preview: http://leo.meeped.co.uk/

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Here is the HTML code:

```
<header>
    <div id="wrapperHeader">
        <div class="scrollable" id="headerContent">
            <section class="headerLogo">
                <a href="index.html"><img id="logoImage" src="assets/elements/logo.png" alt="LOAI Design Studio Logo"/></a>
            </section>
            <section id="headerMenu">
                <nav id="MainMenu"> 
                    <ul class="MainMenu">
                        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="SubMenu" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                            <ul class="subMenu">
                                <li><a href="web-design.html">Web Design</a></li>
                                <li><a href="visual-identity.html">Visual Identity</a></li>
                                <li><a href="photography.html">Photography</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Get In Touch</a></li>
                        <li><a class="getStartedButton" href="get-started.html">Get Started</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Here's the CSS Code:

```
body{
    line-height: 120%;
}

/*Additions*/
.scrollable{
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-transition-property: top, bottom;
    transition-property: top, bottom;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .2s, .2s;
    transition-duration: .2s, .2s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, linear;
    transition-timing-function: linear, linear;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

/*Pages Overall Styling*/ #Page{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 0px;

    z-index: 2;

    -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow:    -3px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow:         -3px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);  
}

/*Content Containers Overall Styling*/.content{
    width: 800px;
}   

/*Header Containers Overall Styling*/#headerContent{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 

    position: fixed;
    margin: auto; 
}

#wrapperHeader{
    background-color: #2D3B53;
    border-bottom: none;

    width: 230px;
    height: 100%;

    position: fixed;
    padding: 0px;

    z-index: 1;
}

/*Main Header Elements*/
.headerLogo, #LogoImage{
    display: none;
}

#headerMenu{
    max-width: 230px;
    float: none;
}

/*Main Menu*/
#MainMenu li{
    padding: 0px;
    float: none;
}

#MainMenu a{
    color: #E0E5EE; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #253145;   

    width: 100%;
    line-height: 50px;

    text-align: left;  
    text-indent: 20px; 
    float: left; 

   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}       

#MainMenu a:hover{
    color: #B8C4D8; 
    background-color: #3D567B;
}   

#MainMenu a.active{
    display: none;
}

#MainMenu li a.getStartedButton{
    color: #74ADB4;
}

#MainMenu li a.getStartedButton:hover{
    background-color: #74ADB4;
    color: #D4E6E8;
}       

/*SubMenu*/
ul.subMenu{
    background-color: #33435F;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;

    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0; left: 0;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.43);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.43);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.43);
}

.subMenu li{
    width: 230px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #DDDDDD;
}

/*Second Header Container & Elements (Hidden From Widescreen)*/
#SecondHeader{
    background-color: #3D5273;

    width: 100%;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: left;

    display: inline-block;
}

.SecondHeader-button{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #3D5273 url('../../assets/elements/nav-icon.png') no-repeat 10px center;

    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-indent: 45px; 

    display: inline-block;
}

/*////////////////////////////*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pseudo class :last-child like this:

```
nav ul li:last-child {
    //style
}
```

Comment: I know mate, but it just right now applied everything to that top section rather to the elements them selfs, have no idea what is going on:/

Answer (score 0):

Are subMenu and SubMenu the same thing? If so, you need to change that in your HTML. Maybe that's the answer to your problem?

Comment: no SubMenu is to be used in the JS to active it the toggle, for the submenu but the submenu is what actually have the elements and styling :/ I have found that the subMenu keep on inherting some styling from the MainMenu like padding, and I can't find out how to change that! even If I gave it it own puddings it will still use the once applied to the MainMenu. any idea? please